# Do we like hats?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, hats

[In 2011, the Gaming Stack Exchange hosted an event called Hat Dash](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2011/12/holiday-2011-hat-dash-the-hattening/), where users earned "hats" for their gravatars by completing certain tasks (analogous to badges):

[image]

Certain actions would trigger the user receiving a hat, which their gravatar could then "wear". For example, editing a post would yield an editor-themed hat (fedora with pen) to the editor.

This year, Stack Exchange is expanding the promotion to any site that wants to participate.

Here's the run down:

- The event will run from 19 December 2012 to 4 January 2013.
- Users will be able to see their entire hat collection on http://winterba.sh (under renovation as of now). That site will also have a landing page, explaining the rules and other details of the event.
- Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see hats, and/or are generally anti-hat will have an "I hate hats" option available.
- The only visual change to the site itself will be the presence of the hats and the "I hate hats" button in the footer.

We need to let Stack Exchange know by 28 November 2012, so vote away on if you want hats, or not.

<sup>(This has been shamelessly snowcloned from [Linguistics SE](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/442/do-we-want-hats).)</sup>
<sup>(Sorry if I stole a task from our diamond moderators.)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking care of it! (was supposed to do it, but been a bit busy this week)...

Comment: みんなさん！ あなた方は帽子が好きですか？投票してください！

Comment: Your winterba.sh link is asking me for a password.

Comment: @Dave Glad to be of help!

Comment: @Troyen It seems the site is being prepared for the event. Here's some screenshots from last year: http://stackexchange.com/promos/2/hat-dash

Comment: +1 (since I can't upvote my own post, let me upvote here)

Comment: @Aarthi English please! This is not a Japanese websit... Oh wait.

Comment: @Aarthi Since you are here.. can you pass it on to the appropriate division that JLU answers to the RSVP with a resounding "yes"?

Comment: I suppose I can! I hope @Dave decides to email me in the next day or so (*hint hint*) but if not, I'll be sure to check here once more. :)

Comment: @Aarthi ok了解しました!

Comment: @ento Ah! I've only ever heard (pardon the romaji) *yokatta ne* because I basically learned all my Japanese from *renzoku*.

Comment: @Aarthi: email sent. And yes, we do want in.

Comment: Messaged received! Be prepared for *hats!* :D