# It's 2013. Do we still like hats?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, hats

Last year, Stack Exchange threw [an end of the year party](http://stackexchange.com/promos/12/winter-bash) featuring special hats, and they're doing it again this year.  But because hats might not be appropriate for all Stack Exchange sites, they're asking each community whether or not they want to participate.

Last time, we decided that [we liked hats](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/979/do-we-like-hats).   So I guess the question is: **do we still like hats?**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jteMl.jpg]

What are hats, you ask?  Well, they're kind of like badges.  You earn them by doing various things.  But unlike badges, they look like hats, and once you've earned a hat you can choose to wear it on your avatar!  And they're purely temporary, just for fun.  They'll disappear once Winter Bash is complete.

**Note:** users who don't want to see hats will be able to click a button labeled "I hate hats".

Comment: I would like to know this year event so that I can get the magician hat(my choice). so +1 :)

Comment: We have about one more week to decide.  If the feedback continues to be positive, I'll send in the message saying we like hats :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The deadline is near, so I checked the current vote totals:

> 7 votes up
>   0 votes down

In my comment about a week ago, I said that if the feedback stayed positive, I'd send in the message saying we like hats.  And since no one voted down or gave any other form of negative feedback in the interim, I decided to send in the message.

### We're getting hats! :-)